mongodb aggregation pipeline joing arrays inside record
I'd like to convert following JSON from collection which I have in database already
{
    "_id": 1,
    "caseName": "testy",
    "pages": [
        {
            "elements": [
            {
                "name": "t1"
            },
            {
                "name": "t2"
            },
            {
                "name": "t3"
            }]
        },
        {
            "elements": [
            {
                "name": "t2"
            },
            {
                "name": "t4"
            },
            {
                "name": "t1"
            }]
        }
    ],
    "dictionary": [
    {
        "name": "t1",
        "description": "descr 1"
    
    },
    {
        "name": "t2",
        "description": "descr 2"
    },
    {
        "name": "t3",
        "description": "descr 3"
    },
    {
        "name": "t4",
        "description": "descr 4"
    }
    ]
}

to something like this using mongodb aggregation pipeline in mongosh command line tool using in linux ubuntu. Id like to run this in mongosh in form of db.survey.aggregate(
{
    "_id": 1,
    "caseName": "testy",
    "pages": [
        {
            "elements": [
            {
                "name": "t1",
                "description": "descr 1"
            },
            {
                "name": "t2",
                "description": "descr 2"
            },
            {
                "name": "t3",
                "description": "descr 3"
            }]
        },
        {
            "elements": [
            {
                "name": "t2",
                "description": "descr 2"
            },
            {
                "name": "t4",
                "description": "descr 4"
            },
            {
                "name": "t1",
                "description": "descr 1"
            }]
        }
    ]
}

How to achieve this? Most of the stuff in the examples are reagrding joing the collections but I dont see joing an arrays within one object . Thats something I cant find.
Thanks
Marcin

https://mongoplayground.net/p/jeriOEeBNjU

do you want to convert your current model into the second one, or just to get the result in the new format? If the second option, @cmgchess gave you the solution. If you want to migrate your current model, you have to use an update operation with aggregate
